# Resize HTML5 Video on a Samsung Smart TV App

Tags: html5-video, samsung-smart-tv

I'm having trouble trying to resize the HTML5 video element in my Samsung Smart TV app. I'm using SDK 2.5. It works fine in the 2011 and 2012 emulators but when I test it on the TV it's stuck in fullscreen.

I've tried using the css and inline elements but neither of them have worked.

My code looks like this:

index page:
`<video id="player"></video>`

Main.js, within the onLoad function:

```
$("#player").attr("src","VIDEO_SOURCE");
$("#player").css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '419px',
    'top': '394px',
    'width': '125px',
    'height': '100px',
});
var v = $("#player").get(0);
v.load();
v.play();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set dimensions as video tag attributes instead of CSS styling, like in example:

```
 <video src="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

There are attributes supported by 2.5 SDK:

- autoplay
- controls
- height
- loop
- preload
- src
- width

Check the Samsung docs about this topic:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_2/reference/HTML%20Specification.html#HTML5%20and%20Samsung%20Smart%20TV%20SDK

More flexibility with video but more complex gives you the Samsung's Player API:
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/View/Developer_Documentation/Samsung_SmartTV_Developer_Documentation_2.5/API_Reference/JavaScript_APIs/Device_API/Player

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried this first and it didn't work either. I've been using Samsung's Player but had problems with it playing mp4's

Comment: mp4 on samsung API player works good. Try to play with Samsung's demos.

Comment: Hmm I go it working with the Samsung API player. The problem I had was that when the video was buffered the screen flickered black before it started playing. I changed the video source and it works fine now, maybe something to do with the bit rate.

Comment: yes the problem of screen flickering is caused by different videos fps. so when you make VOD app try to use the same video encoding settings to all your videos.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but i have some code you can use
dont forget to import jquery

```
<HTML>
<script>
//Wait for the DOM to load
$(window).load(function()
{
    var $bodyElement = $('body');

});


//Wait for the Videos to load To add Event listeners
$(document).ready(function()
{
});



//Initialise Dom Scripts here
this.InitialiseDomScripts = function()
{
    AddDomReadyListeners();
    return true; //return true for Initialisation
}

this.InitialiseDocReadyScripts = function()
{
    AddDocReadyListeners();
    OnResize();

    return true;
}

this.AddDomReadyListeners = function()
{
    //Add a window listener, see when the window is resized
    $(window).resize(OnResize);
}

this.AddDocReadyListeners = function()
{
    //Add a listeners to videos to see when the meta data has loaded
    $('video').bind("loadeddata",function(_VideoEvent)
    {
        OnLoadedVideoData(_VideoEvent);
    });
}

this.OnLoadedVideoData = function(_VideoEvent)
{
    var loadedVideoElement = _VideoEvent.target;
    if($(loadedVideoElement).hasClass('StretchtoFit'))
    {
        ResizeVideo(loadedVideoElement);
    }

}

this.OnResize = function()
{
    //Loop through all of the videos that are marked as stretch to fit
    $('.StretchtoFit').each(function()
    {
        var CurrentChild = this;
        ResizeVideo(CurrentChild);
    });
}

this.ResizeVideo = function(_VideoElement)
{
    $VideoElement = $(_VideoElement); //Cache Jquery reference of this
    var iOriginalVideoHeight =  _VideoElement.videoHeight;
    var iCurrentVideoHeight = $VideoElement.height();
    var iVideoContainerHeight = $VideoElement.parent().height();
    var iCurrentScale = iOriginalVideoHeight/iCurrentVideoHeight;
    var iScaleY = (iVideoContainerHeight / iOriginalVideoHeight)*iCurrentScale;


    //Important to note: Set the origin to the top left corner (0% 0%), or else the position of the video goes astray
     $VideoElement.css({
        "transform-origin": "0% 0%",
        "transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")",
        "-ms-transform-origin" : "0% 0% ", /* IE 9 */
        "-ms-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* IE 9 */
        "-moz-transform-origin" : "0% 0%", /* Firefox */
        "-moz-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* Firefox */
        "-webkit-transform-origin": "0% 0%", /* Safari and Chrome */
        "-webkit-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")", /* Safari and Chrome */
        "-o-transform-origin":"0% 0%", /* Opera */
        "-o-transform":"scaleY(" + iScaleY +")" /* Opera */
     }); 
}

</script>
<body>
<video class="StretchtoFit"  autoplay preload id="video"><source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
</body>
</html>
```